# angular-chart chart-line not working

Tags: angularjs, charts, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm trying out [`angular-chart`](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) with Angular 1.5. I copied an example right off their home page:

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
  chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options"
  chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick">
</canvas>
```

I even copied the sample JavaScript into my controller. Yet absolutely nothing shows up.

In angular-chart [Bug #591](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/591), somebody else is having the same problem. I opened [Bug #594](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/594) when that bug was closed.

Their site looks so professional---surely their library isn't broken! I must be making some stupid mistake. Any ideas?

(On second thought, looking at the [GitHub project](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js), it seems like it hasn't been updated for quite a while. Maybe I should try to find a different charting library for Angular.)

Comment: I gave up and switched to [Angular-nvD3](https://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/), built on top of [NVD3](http://nvd3.org/), in turn built on top of [D3](https://d3js.org/) (although currently only D3 v3.x is supported). D3 is the hugely extensive, flexible, and popular data-driven document library which goes far beyond charts. It uses SVG, and the data representation for a scatter plot is more intuitive that Angular Chart. I'm pretty happy with it overall so far.

Answer (score 1):

okay, This might not make any sense. But I only put the canvas element within a div and it worked

The canvas needs to be in a div wrapper apparently .. hope it may help someone